# Why is my Virtual Machine sending MDNS requests in the internal network?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, wireshark, mdns

Following setup:

Windows 10 host system runs 2 Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Machines from VirtualBox.
Both the VMs have their network adapter set to "internal" mode, which means only an internal network can be set up.
Now I assigned static IP addresses to the VMs, disabling DHCP. Both the VMs run in the same local network.

When I use one VM to ping the other one (which works perfectly), Wireshark shows me that the VM is using the "MDNS" (Multicast DNS) protocol at the beginning.
It is only sending a request (via IPv4 and IPv6 seperately) but is not getting any response.

The request includes the name of the host that needs to be resolved: `_nmea-0183._tcp.local`

Do you know why the VM is sending these MDNS messages and why it is looking for a host with that particular name?

[Screenshot of the Wireshark recording showing the MDNS messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaU2m.png)

Comment: this is interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183 Do you have any GPS devices or related services on the machines?

Comment: so I know that mDNS is commonly associated with Zero-conf/AVAHI/Bonjour networks, and is used for endpoint and service discovery. that tracks with the `.local` url. I have to assume your system has a zero-conf capable client on it, and its trying to find NMEA services. since zero-conf networks are "dynamic" from an infrastructure POV, it kinda makes sense that there would be a lot of "just checking to see if X service is available on this LAN".  I've personally never tried to maintain a zero-conf network, so thats about all I know on the topic, but hopefully it helps you track it down.

Comment: Have you installed some [NMEA tool](https://opencpn.org/wiki/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=opencpn:supplementary_software:nmea_instruments)?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I set up the VM freshly from the Ubuntu iso file and installed nothing else. How can I check if any of these `NMEA tools` is installed?